# Spray, Akka-http and Play, Which is the best bet for a new HTTP/REST project

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, spray, akka-http

I'm going to develop new HTTP/REST services using Scala and Akka Actors.

I have experience working with Play, but I don't really need a complete web Framework.
From what I read, I think Spray is a suitable choice. 
My question come from the future of Spray after the new arrived AKKA-HTTP.

Does the Spray project will grow independently from the Akka-HTTP project, or are the two project going to be merged into one Akka-HTTTP?

What is the impact of this if I start developing with Spray?
Also I read that Play will integrate AKKA-HTTP. 
So I finally wonder if a should not go with Play?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think Spray should merge in AkkaHTTP. It was announced, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Spray is production ready, but the development team (Mathias Doenitz) works for Typesafe on Akka-http now.

The status of Akka-http is ["development preview"](http://akka.io/docs/).  There are vague promises of a full release "within a few months", but nothing you can take to the bank.

*Edited 29-July-2015:*

> The status of Akka-HTTP is now "release candidate" with version 1.0 RC4. 
>   Its functionality is largely competing with spray.io, and the common expectation is that spray.io will lose it's development momentum.
>   At this time I would not recommend spray.io for new projects anymore.

Jonas Boner from Typesafe has referred to Akka-http as "Spray 2.0".  So don't expect any future versions of Spray and at some point you'll have to make the switch.  I saw Jonas' Akka-http presentation at Scala Days and it looks like porting Spray code to Akka-http should be straight forward as the DSL is mostly unchanged (even though the underlying implementation of the library will be different).

To answer your questions specifically: Spray is finished as a separate project, it is being imported into Akka under the name Akka-http (not a merge as Akka didn't have any equivalent before hand).  If you need to start development now go with Spray, if you can afford to work with the inevitable bugs in a preview release go with Akka-http.  Your Spray code will never stop working, but it won't be supported either outside of minor bug fixes.  All new functionality will be added in Akka-http, so instead of updating to Spray 2.0 you update to Akka-http.

Comment: A year on: What is the current status?

Answer (score 2):

You have already given answer to your question in your comment. As long as if you don't need to deal with UI I would suggest go with **Akka-HTTP or Spray.io**.

I don't think you will have impact if you starts with Spray.io as there are many projects running their production environment on Spray.

For more details please refer below link.

[FAQ SPray.io](http://downloads.typesafe.com/website/general/Spray-FAQ.pdf)

[Typesafe Press Release](http://www.marketwired.com/press-release/Typesafe-Reactive-Platform-Acquires-New-High-Performance-HTTP-Foundation-1841738.htm)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have to learn everything from scratch, I would recommend choosing spray - Akka hhtp documentation is really incomplete and a lot of route directives are not implemented yet on akka.http. I started with akka but I was forced to go to spray...

Comment: The docs have improved significantly with the Akka HTTP 2.0-M1 release, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

[Typesafe gets Spray(ed) | @typesafe](http://www.typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-gets-sprayed)

> The Akka/Spray integration—named Akka HTTP—will provide an ideal way
>   of producing and consuming embeddable REST services.

Answer (score 0):

As per Johannes Rudolph

> if you want to provide an HTTP interface to (maybe already existing) akka services, then that's what akka-http is for

source: https://gitter.im/akka/akka?at=5874fc9761fac5a03dbe1a6f